# Jquery.ajax requesting a 'Get' to Web API 2 backend is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a Web API 2 project, and I am trying to write my front-end with JQuery. I am having issues, and quite frankly, some confusing behaviors, when trying to GET the user (login).

Backend:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using AngularJSWebApiEmpty.Models;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace AngularJSWebApiEmpty.Controllers
{
public class ArtistsController : ApiController
{
    private BANDIOappEntities db = new BANDIOappEntities();

    public ArtistsController()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    // GET: api/Artists
    public IQueryable<Artist> GetArtists()
    {
        return db.Artists;
    }

    // GET: api/Artists/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Artist))]
    public Artist Get(string username, string password)
    {
        Artist artist = null;
        artist = (db.Artists.Include("BandMates").Where(x => x.UserName == username && x.Password == password).First<Artist>());
        return artist;
    }

    // PUT: api/Artists/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutArtist(int id, Artist artist)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != artist.ArtistId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(artist).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ArtistExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Artists
    [ResponseType(typeof(Artist))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostArtist(Artist artist)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Artists.Add(artist);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = artist.ArtistId }, artist);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Artists/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Artist))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteArtist(int id)
    {
        Artist artist = await db.Artists.FindAsync(id);
        if (artist == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Artists.Remove(artist);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(artist);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ArtistExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Artists.Count(e => e.ArtistId == id) > 0;
    }
}
}
```

JQuery

```
    ....
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/api/Artists/5',
        data: {"username": login.username, "password": login.password},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
```

Keep in mind I was originally using Angular.js to hit this same exact API without any issues...

When I run this in the Chrome browser, I ALWAYS get '{readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}'. Everything I am reading on the subject keeps telling me it is a cross-domain issue, but this is not the issue here.

I then decided to try this using the IE browser, and suddenly I am not getting this error. However, instead of returning the artist that belongs to the credentials, it is returning all artists. Also, the credentials do not appear to need to be valid, no matter what I send I am getting all artists.

I am extremely new to JQuery, so maybe this is something that is easily resolved? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to `JSON.stringify` the object before sending in the `$.ajax` request?

Comment: Why do you specify `dataType: 'jsonp'`?

Comment: /api/Artists/5 ? Why 5 ? sounds extra param . Try without "/5"

Comment: oops the jsonp was troubleshooting I left in the code, it was not originally there. yes I have tried stringify with same results.  that was how the API defined it when it was scafolded, I will try without '/5' as soon as I get a chance. can anyone explain the difference in behaviours between the browsers? Thanks again!

Comment: great, and change your method "GetArtist" to "Get"

Comment: Post the full code of your controller please.  Also, post any custom routing logic you may have.  By default, Web API uses the HTTP verb as the method name, unless explicitly noted.  So the method name should be "Get", not GetArtists.  Also, by default, Web API uses the controller name as the resource name.  If the class name is ArtistController, your URL referring to "api/Artists" will NOT hit it.

Comment: I tried changing GetArtist() to Get() and removing "/5" from request - no change. I have reverted back and updated post to show entire controller. I am starting to feel I am in over my head...haha please help!

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like everyone jumped ship on helping me figure this out. I decided to create a new API project and start all over with JQuery rather than Angular.js, (I was able to get this to work no sweat with the Angular project, but have nothing but issues changing it over).

Same behavior, but then I noticed the page jumping every time I clicked the button to login... so then I figured out I had to tell it not use the default browser behavior, so I changed my 'click' routine to do so:

```
$('#signin_submit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var login = {
        username: $('#signin_username').val(),
        password: $('#signin_password').val()
    }

    console.log(login);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: './api/Artists',
        data: login,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

..and suddenly it works on both browsers without any issues! Can I explain why the default behavior was screwing this up? Nope. But hopefully this may be able to help someone as fresh to this as me out in the future?